# JavaFX Move Node Between Different Panes

Tags: drag-and-drop, javafx

The diagram below should help this be as clear as possible.

I have 3 panes A B and C.  B and C are children of A, and B has children of it's own (white boxes).  With drag and drop, I can move B's children anywhere inside B and be able to pick them up again, but if dragged over to C, or even the small part of A they can be dropped but can't be picked up again.

I use the basic controls.  To drag I use imgView.setOnMouseDragged.

So how can I drag from one pane A, to pane B or C and still be allowed to pick up and drag the object again?

[image: example]